# Export BDC in 2010 and import in 2013

Tags: 2010, 2013, upgrade, bdc

Can I export a BDC in SP2010 and import and use it in SP2013?

Comment: Are you trying to migrate the Service Application or just the Model?

Comment: Im about to migrate the Serivce Application from 2010 to 2013.

Answer (score 1):

This involves first upgrading `Secure Store Service Application` and then upgrading `Business Data Connectivity Service Application`

You can follow steps outlined in this article https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj839719.aspx